Expo app not starting when updating to latest version of expo sdk
I was working on a project made from react-native-expo it was all working fine but one day when I tried to open it using expo go app it did not started instead it showed me warning on a blue screen that " SDK version is updated to 51 and expo go now uses SDK 51 so you should either install SDK 50 version of expo go or update your project to the latest version of expo " then I updated my project to the latest version after it started giving me error " main has not been registered and resizeMode is not defined " I tried to fix it about 2 to 3 days but it was not fixed then what it did is that i deleted the node_modules and package_lock.json file and ran npm install in my project and started it then all the errors were removed but now when i am starting my project it is not starting instead it is just showing a blue screen where it is written "Network response timed out " or "Sorry about that you can go back to expo home or try to reload the project " i tried every thing that i can to fix this but it is not working can you tell how can i fix it please
enter image description here
I was expecting that after the update my will work as it was working before but it instead gave me error "Main has not been registered this happens when metro is running from the wrong folder " and "resizeMode is not defined " then I deleted the node_modules and package_lock.json file and ran npm install then every error fixed but then when i started my app it is not working instead it keep showing " Something Went wrong ( Network response timed out ) " "Something went wrong ( Sorry about that you can go back to expo home or try to reload the project) "

I'm having same issue. I was able to start it with --tunnel but I don't want to have to. any ideas?
